# Set notification if is two product category in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to set notifications when I have products from these two different categories inside the card in `WooCommerce`.

This is the code which I using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart' );
function webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart() {

    $cat_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if ( has_term( 'cat1', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) &&
             has_term( 'cat2', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cat_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $cat_in_cart ) {
        $notice = 'Notification';
        wc_print_notice($notice, 'notice');
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly if I only set one category, but when I set two categories, for some reason I don't have results nor errors.

Comment: Do you need to check for if both are in the cart, or either one of them? You have `&&` which means the cart item has **both** categories. You might consider using the `||` (or) instead. You can also simplify the code, since `has_term` can accept an object, you can just pass `$cart_item`.

Comment: Also, you won't get errors since you aren't error checking. Your code is still valid, but none of the conditions are being met so it skips processing the `if` statement.

Comment: @disinfor I need to check for both. So, when I have product 1 from category x and product 2 from category y in the card, I need to get a notification.

Comment: Yeah, you need stronger logic than what you have. Currently you have _"If the product in the cart has `cat1` and `cat2`, then set `$cat_in_cart` to true."_ If I understand you correctly, you need to check when 2 different products are in the cart AND if one has `cat1` and the other has `cat2`. Is that correct? Do the products share category terms, or will, for example, product 1 only have category x (maybe other categories, but not category y) and the reverse for product 2?

Comment: @disinfor I have 5 products in `cat1` and 5 products in `cat2`. I need notification if at least 1 product from `cat1` and 1 product from `cat2` been added to the card.

Comment: Cool. That makes more sense. I think I can help you out.

Comment: @disinfor I found a solution, it is not so great, but it works. I've just posted a solution but feel free to send me your example.

Comment: Ha! I posted my answer as you wrote yours. It's really the same thing, so you're on the right path!

Comment: @disinfor Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you want. The problem is in your original function, is that you were checking *each* product if it had both categories.

You need to split up the the conditions and then check the final conditions.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart' );

function webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart() {

    $cat_one_in_cart = false;
    $cat_two_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( 'cat1', 'product_cat', $cart_item ) ) {
            $cat_one_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }

        if ( has_term( 'cat2', 'product_cat', $cart_item ) ) {
            $cat_two_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $cat_one_in_cart && $cat_two_in_cart ) {
        $notice = 'Notification';
        wc_print_notice($notice, 'notice');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart' );
function webroom_check_if_product_category_is_in_cart() {

    $cat1_in_cart = false;
    $cat2_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if ( has_term( 'cat1', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cat1_in_cart = true;
        } elseif(has_term( 'cat2', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] )){
            $cat2_in_cart = true;
        }
    }

    if ($cat1_in_cart === true && $cat2_in_cart === true) {
        $notice = 'Notification';
        wc_print_notice($notice, 'notice');
    }
}
```